# Plot PCM output in Matlab (MP3 decoder)

Tags: matlab, mp3, pcm, decoder

I am doing a mp3 decoder project and I have built a function to decode a song in mp3 format:

```
function [PCM_output,frequency] = decode(mp3song)
```

At the end of the code, I am adding a few lines to plot the PCM waveform:

```
t=0:0.01:120; 
plot(t,PCM_output);
title('PCM waveform');
```

But it shows error:

> Vectors must be the same lengths.

How to solve the error? Besides, is it possible to output the decoded song in PCM format?

Additional Question:
I want to compare the mp3 and PCM output as shown in the Figures below:
[MP3 - Amplitude vs Time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ovnz.png)

[PCM - Amplitude vs Time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMH9u.png)

Why does the PCM has two output overlay together? Is it because of the left and right channel at the output?

Comment: Just wondering why the "r" tag.

Comment: Typing `length(t)` and `length(`PCM_output(1,:))` might help troubleshooting

Comment: I don't think there is a PCM format for audio file, but you can just `wavwrite` it and try to hear it.

Comment: @brainkz, the `length(PCM_output(1,:))` is 9861120 while the time taken to decode is 10094s. Is it possible to plot the two variables in a graph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try to plot your sound wave, you just need your `t` vector to be the same length as your `PCM_output`. So, instead of `t=0:0.01:120` you need

```
t=linspace(0,120,length(PCM_output(1,:)));
```